# Proving independence on frames of the determinant of a linear map in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using summation index

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Consider the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^3.$ Given a right-handed orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}$ we have the permutation symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ defined to be $\epsilon_{ijk}=(e_i\times e_j)\cdot e_k$ which is $+1$ for $ijk=123,231,312,$ and $-1$ for $ijk=321,213,132$ and $0$ otherwise. Now suppose that $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e_i'\}$ are two coordinate frames then we have the change of basis tensor $A$ mapping from $\{e_i\}$ to $\{e_i'\}$, defined to be $A=A_{ij} e_i \otimes e_j$ where $A_{ij}=e_i \cdot e_j'$ and $\otimes$ is the dyadic product of two vectors defined to be $(a\otimes b)v=(b\cdot v)a$.

Now we have the properties $A_{ij}A_{jk}=\delta_{jk}$ and $A_{ik}A_{lk}=\delta_{il}$.

The determinant function on second-order tensors is the mapping defined to be
$$\det S=\det[S]=\epsilon_{ijk}[S]_{1i}[S]_{2j}[S]_{3k}$$ where $[S]$ denotes the component matrix representation of S in the frame $\{e_i\}$.

My goal is to show that $\det[S]=\det[S]'$ from the definition above given that $[S]'$ is the matrix representation of $S$ in the frame $\{e_i'\}$.

I have the relation $[S]_{ij}=A_{ik}[S]'_{kl}A_{jl}$.
Replacing this above gives $\det[S]=\epsilon_{ijk}A_{1m}[S]'_{mn}A_{il} A_{2u}[S]'_{uv}A_{jh} A_{3b}[S]'_{bc}A_{kp}$.

I can't show how to reduce this to get $\epsilon_{ijk}[S]'_{1i}[S]'_{2j}[S]'_{3k}$.

I would greatly appreciate any help on reducing this equation.

Comment: This expression $\epsilon_{ijk}A_{1m}[S]'_{mn}A_{il} A_{2u}[S]'_{uv}A_{jh} A_{3b}[S]'_{bc}A_{kp}$ does not look correct to me. The indices $l,v,h$ can not be free indices.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield I think you are right. How should I replace $[S]_{1i}, [S]_{2j}[S]_{3k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\det(S)=\varepsilon_{ijk}S_{1i}S_{2j}S_{3k}$ and $S_{lm}=A_{ln}S_{nt}^\prime A_{mt}$, then
\begin{align}
\det(S)&=\varepsilon_{ijk}(A_{1n}S_{nt}^\prime A_{it})(A_{2p}S_{pq}^\prime A_{jq})(A_{3r}S_{rs}^\prime A_{ks})\\
&=(\varepsilon_{ijk}A_{it}A_{jq}A_{ks})(S_{nt}^\prime S_{pq}^\prime S_{rs}^\prime)(A_{1n}A_{2p}A_{3r})\\
&=(\varepsilon_{tqs}\det(A^T))(S_{nt}^\prime S_{pq}^\prime S_{rs}^\prime)(A_{1n}A_{2p}A_{3r})\\
&=\det(A^T)(\varepsilon_{tqs}S_{nt}^\prime S_{pq}^\prime S_{rs}^\prime)(A_{1n}A_{2p}A_{3r})\\
&=\det(A^T)(\varepsilon_{npr}\det(S^\prime))(A_{1n}A_{2p}A_{3r})\\
&=\det(A^T)\det(S^\prime)(\varepsilon_{npr}A_{1n}A_{2p}A_{3r})\\
&=\det(A^T)\det(S^\prime)\det(A)\\
&=\det(S^\prime),
\end{align}
where we have used the fact that $A_{ik}A_{lk}=\delta_{il}\implies AA^T=I\implies\det(A)\det(A^T)=1.$

It is worth pointing out that all this calculation is unnecessary, because if $S_{lm}=A_{ln}S_{nt}^\prime A_{mt}$, then

$S=AS^\prime A^T\implies\det(S)=\det(A)\det(S^\prime)\det(A^T)\implies\det(S)=\det(S^\prime).$

Comment: Why is $\epsilon_{ijk}A_{it}A_{jq}A_{ks}=\epsilon_{tqs}\det(A^T)$?

Comment: Because $A_{it}=(A^T)_{ti}$, $A_{jq}=(A^T)_{qj}$, and $A_{ks}=(A^T)_{sk}$.

Comment: Yes I know that I'm wondering why the multiplication by $\epsilon_{tqs}$

Comment: See the EXAMPLE 1.1-9, at pages 10 and 11 of the book https://vtk.ugent.be/w/images/9/96/Wiskundige_ingenieurstechnieken_-_Introduction_to_Tensor_Calculus.pdf